# lock a Runnable until finished

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using Runnable as a loop in Android. As this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new looper(m_mainView, this),0, Rate);
```

Which runs every 'Rate' milliseconds.

The looper is as this:

```
class looper extends TimerTask
{
    private ImageView img;
    Context c;


    public looper(ImageView imgView, Context context)
    {
        this.img = imgView;
        this.c = context;
    }

    public void run()
    {   
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
....
```

I would like to lock the code inside `run()` until it is finished, so that if it is called before finished - the thread that calls will return and finish.

I've tried a `synchronized(Object)` approach inside `run()` which didn't work. Also tried a Mutex, which also didn't work.

Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `looper` object is solely owned by the `timer.schedule` so no-one can call that object's `run` method except the `timer.schedule`. If the `run` method takes longer that the period you have specified then it is likely that the run method will be called again before it completes - especially since you have passed off the actual running of the the task to the UI thread.

You have two simple alternatives:

1. Set a flag in your `run` method indicating that you are running and make `run` do nothing if it is set.
2. Fire off the timer after a fixed delay only, not with a repeat time. At the end of your run, fire it off again.

For 1:

```
class Looper extends TimerTask {
  // ** Add this **
  volatile boolean running = false;

  public Looper() {
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // ** Add this **
    if (!running) {
      running = true;
      try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
          }

        });
        // ** Add this **
      } finally {
        running = false;
      }

    }
  }

}
```

Second method:

```
timer.schedule(new looper(m_mainView, this, Rate),new Date());
...
class Looper extends TimerTask {
  final long rate;
  final Looper looper;

  public Looper(long rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
    looper = this;
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // ...
        new Timer().schedule(looper, new Date(new Date().getTime() + rate));
      }

    });

  }

}
```

Comment: BTW - the first one, didn't work at all - which is strange. I've tried it with a mutex, a synchronized method and just a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `synchronized` to the method declaration like this:

```
public synchronized void run()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is there any risk that the run method will be called again? If that's true it sounds like a design deficiency to me.
Second, instead of TimerTask, you might be better off using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) instead. That's the standard, simplest and safest way of executing scheduled tasks at a fixed interval. Your user code won't be accessible from anything but the executor service and you can get a ScheduledFuture from it to get a return value so that you know when the task is done (the ScheduledFuture blocks when you call get()).
Take a look at Java Concurrency in Practice for more...